# How to know this NSObject is class or protocol in swift?

Tags: swift

In swift , super class and protocol is write together like this

[image]

Most of times ,this will not make misunderstanding , But because there is a NSObject class and a NSObject protocol with the same name, How to distinguish them?

[image]
And how the compiler know to use the NSObject class not the NSObject protocol?

And If I want to use the NSObject protocol not the NSObject class , how to write the class declaration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The protocol is called [NSObjectProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobjectprotocol) not [NSObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject) which is a class. If you want something to conform to `NSObjectProtocol` exclusively use that:

```
protocol MyProtocol: NSObjectProtocol { }
```

On the other hand `NSObject` conforms to `NSObjectProtocol`. So in conclusion by inheriting a class from `NSObject` means it's refering to the `NSObject` class and (not the `NSObject` objective-c `@protocol`) ipso facto conforms it to `NSObjectProtocol`.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift, `NSObject` protocol is imported as `NSObjectProtocol` so there is no naming conflict.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject?language=objc